# How to change the text paragraph depending on which image is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the image and paragraph based on what is clicked. Currently, the image is changed based on what is clicked, but not the paragraph. I'm having some trouble having the text correspond to the image. I'm new to programming so if you guys have any ideas that would help. Thanks, and let me know if you guys need any more information.

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
   var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
   var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
   expandImg.src = imgs.src;

   // use 'display:table-cell' to keep elements side-by-side
   expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
   imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
 }
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'futuralight';
    src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'tekoregular';
    src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
    src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
    src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
  * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
  }
  
  .topnav {
    background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'futuralight';
    font-weight: 900;
  }
  
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 21px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 19px;
    position: relative;
    left: 2%;
  }
  
  .topnav a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 6px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
  
  .topnav a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  
  .topnav a.active-menu:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 6px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
  
  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  
  /* Style the images inside the grid */
  
  .column img {
    opacity: 0.85;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .column img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .totalbody{
    background-color: #EEF0FC;
    height:5000px;
  }
  
  
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  
  
  /* The expanding image container */
  
  #expandedImg{
    width:20%;
  }
  /* Expanding image text */
  
  
  
  /* image paragraph */
  
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 5px;
    float:right;
    right:30px;
    top:120px;
  }
  
  #expanded-wrapper{
    width:100%;
  }
  
  /* Closable button inside the expanded image */
  
  
  .row {
    position: absolute;
    top: 600px;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 830px) and (min-width: 760px) {
    .topnav {
      background-color: yellow;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 759px) and (min-width: 646px) {
    .topnav {
      background-color: red;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
    .topnav {
      background-color: black;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body class= 'totalbody'>
  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>
  
  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
        <img id="expandedImg">
        <p id="img-paragraph">image paragraph content goes here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/Petngc9GmDGVfvqWtZW1uw--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTcwNTtoPTM4MC43/https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/p2FH9i2oATkHA6O0ucuC9A--~B/aD0yMTY7dz00MDA7c209MTthcHBpZD15dGFjaHlvbg--/https://media.zenfs.com/en/prnewswire.com/d908212583d777d158af74cb171ec897"
        alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://engineering.wustl.edu/news/PublishingImages/141020_jwb_brookings_007-1915x768.jpg?RenditionID=1" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/McKelvey-courtyard.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
  </div>
      
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to get to the Paragraph part. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @CanUver When I click on one of the images, a paragraph shows up. The problem is this paragraph is the same for each image, and I want the paragraphs to show different text. Do you understand what I'm saying or do you need me to explain further?

Comment: Where are the different text which you want to show for the different images? From where will you get it from?

Comment: @AhmedHammad I didn't include them in this code sketch. I had some in the original code, but I deleted them because they were not working. These text boxes can be full of whatever text. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `data` attribute for each image and then I selected them in javascript and projected them into paragraph div.

```js
 function myFunction(imgs) {
      var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
      expandImg.src = imgs.src;
      var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');

      expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
      imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
      
      let imageParagraph = imgs.dataset.paragraph; // ı added codes
      imgParagraph.innerText = imageParagraph
    }
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.85;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 5000px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  width: 20%;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) and (min-width: 760px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 759px) and (min-width: 646px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class='totalbody'>

<header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph">image paragraph content goes here</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%"
        data-paragraph="Nature" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img
        src="https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/Petngc9GmDGVfvqWtZW1uw--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTcwNTtoPTM4MC43/https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/p2FH9i2oATkHA6O0ucuC9A--~B/aD0yMTY7dz00MDA7c209MTthcHBpZD15dGFjaHlvbg--/https://media.zenfs.com/en/prnewswire.com/d908212583d777d158af74cb171ec897"
        alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);" data-paragraph="Snow">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://engineering.wustl.edu/news/PublishingImages/141020_jwb_brookings_007-1915x768.jpg?RenditionID=1"
        alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);" data-paragraph="Mountains">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/McKelvey-courtyard.jpg" alt="Lights"
        style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);" data-paragraph="Lights">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: How do I do that, but with paragraphs. I don't understand how to get the paragraphs to correspond to the image.

Comment: How would I style the text in those boxes?

Comment: `#img-paragraph { // Your Styles }`   You've already chosen this. Just write down the styling you want. They will work. Example `color: red;`

Answer (score 0):

Let's add a custom attribute to every image named `parag`, we can then use the value of this attribute to set to to `img-paragraph`:

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
   var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
   expandImg.src = imgs.src;
   var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
   imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("parag");

   expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
   imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.85;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 5000px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  width: 20%;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) and (min-width: 760px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 759px) and (min-width: 646px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph">image paragraph content goes here</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" parag="Parapraph #1" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/Petngc9GmDGVfvqWtZW1uw--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTcwNTtoPTM4MC43/https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/p2FH9i2oATkHA6O0ucuC9A--~B/aD0yMTY7dz00MDA7c209MTthcHBpZD15dGFjaHlvbg--/https://media.zenfs.com/en/prnewswire.com/d908212583d777d158af74cb171ec897"
        alt="Snow" style="width:100%" parag="Parapraph #2" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://engineering.wustl.edu/news/PublishingImages/141020_jwb_brookings_007-1915x768.jpg?RenditionID=1" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" parag="Parapraph #3" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/McKelvey-courtyard.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" parag="Parapraph #4" onclick="myFunction(this);">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: By whatever I want I meant the paragraph that corresponds to each image, not truly whatever I want...

Comment: Sir, you didn't include any source for the paragraphs in your code!! The images doesn't have any corresponding text to them!! From where should I get them?!

Comment: I apologize, that is part of my problem. I don't know how to add any source text that corresponds with the images.

Comment: @rf19 I added a suggestion for using custom paragraph for every image. Check the edited answer please.